# Is there any GCP managed service is available to store python whl files and use them in requirements.txt

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, python-packaging, python-wheel

I have one enterprise application built using python flask. There are several individual modules are there which I converted then to whl files and referring them in other modules inside requirements.txt.

Is there any GCP service available to store these whl files other than GCS so that I can directly refer them inside requirements.txt

Comment: Currently in alpha: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/manage-packages

Answer (score 1):

There is an alpha feature in [artifact registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/quickstart) that creates a private pipy for you. You should be able to store your wheel file and to get them, with pip, when you need it (and if you have the permission for).

*I'm not a python expert and I didn't tested it, but the promise is here. I will be happy if you provide me feedbacks on this feature!*